# Loading Javascript into Div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I am trying to place a constantly updating Donation Ticker on my website that is currently located at http://www.ronpaul2012.com in the . I have tried several solutions around stackoverflow including iframes, but my search abilities are either lacking or there is some java their site is running that I don't know how to work with (or I don't know a thing about javascript, but thats neither here nor there). I played around with several variations and tried some document.ready calls, but I am not sure why nothing comes up.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Ron Paul Donation Ticker</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<script>
$('#ticker').load('https://secure.ronpaul2012.com/ #tickerContainer');
</script>

<body>

<div id="ticker"></div>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean Java or Javascript?

Comment: Consider removing political opinions from your question about code.

Comment: @paislee sorry, thought the policy of indiscriminately bombing other countries eventually leading to a nuclear apocalypse was more of an inevitable fate as opposed to a political opinion

Comment: @Danejir thx. maybe i like RP too. SO is just not the place for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the javascript is executing before the div is present. Use this to make the code wait to execute until the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('#ticker').load('https://secure.ronpaul2012.com/#tickerContainer');
 });
```

Also, I removed the space from your URL, which may have been an issue with loading at the right spot.